# Fractional Derivative of a Taylor Series?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, fractional-calculus

I have a function defined only by it's taylor series: $$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k$$

Obviously, integer derivatives can be defined as $$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{(k-n)!}x^{k-n}$$

However, this completely fails if $n$ is not an integer and $x=0$; every term vanishes, which is obviously incorrect. Is there a better way to take a fractional derivative of a Taylor series?

Comment: Why do you say every term vanishes? The fractional derivative of $x^n$ exists and is nonzero.

Comment: $0^n$ is zero if $n>0$. And as I said, I'm obviously not taking it correctly.

Comment: Oh I see your problem now. You're taking the derivative and _then_ evaluating at $0$?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I think the issue is that when you take the $\frac{3}{2}$ derivative of, say, $x$, you don't get a zero value. The $\frac{3}{2}$ derivative of $x$ is defined to be $\frac{\Gamma(1+1)}{\Gamma(1-\frac{3}{2}+1)}x^{1-\frac{3}{2}} = \frac{\Gamma(2)}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}x^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ since $\Gamma(n+1) = n!$ if $n$ is an integer.

Comment: Yes, yes. What I'm asking is: What is the proper way to take the, say, $\frac{1}{2}$ derivative of a taylor series? Is it correct to just take the $\frac{1}{2}$ derivative of every term individually?

Comment: Yes I would say so. You would probably have to do a little bit of analysis to show that it really works but I don't see why it wouldn't. You can differentiate term-by-term for a finite sum so it should carry over to the infinite sum case. But of course, that doesn't mean it's going to give wonderful results as my example shows. You can run into divergences when you try evaluating at points.

Comment: Then $f^{(n)}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{\Gamma(k+1)}x^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{\Gamma(k+1)} \frac{\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma(k-n+1)}x^{k-n} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{\Gamma(k-n+1)}x^{k-n}$, which is exactly what my original solution is, and vanishes at 0 if n isn't an integer.

Comment: No it does not vanish. $k-n$ in your exponent doesn't have to be a positive number..

Comment: Right, so the first term has 0^{-n}, which is undefined. Even if you differentiate it as a constant, you get $\frac{f(0) x^{-n}}{\Gamma(1-n)}$, which is also undefined at 0.

Comment: Correct. The non-integer derivatives cause some divergences at $0$ it seems.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wxmnyhy8gm

Comment: Consider $f(x)=e^x$, and compare $f^{(n)}(x)$ to $f^{(n+1)}(x)$ via your methods.