# Fractional derivatives of Gamma function

Tags: gamma-function, fractional-calculus

For integer $n \geq 0$, we have $\dfrac{d^n}{ds^n} x^s = (\ln x)^n \,x^s$. From this it follows, for example, that $$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}\ln^n x \,dx= \Gamma^{(n)}(1)$$
Question: is there a way of defining fractional derivatives in which it makes sense to say that 
$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}\ln^q x \, dx= \Gamma^{(q)}(1) $$ for rational $q$, and are there values of $q$ for which this can be evaluated in terms of ordinary special functions?

Comment: See [fractional calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus).

Comment: Also, $\quad|\zeta^{(n)}(m)|\approx\dfrac{n!}{(m-1)^{n+1}}$.

Comment: It's $\Gamma^{{\rm\left(n\right)}}\left(1\right)$.

Comment: If it holds for rational $q$, it holds for real $q$, assuming it is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

One way to check the answer to see if it holds by induction.  Using $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{d^k}{dx^k}=\frac{d^{n+k}}{dx^{n+k}}$, and assuming it is continuous as a function of $n,k$, then you should be able to verify that your answer works.

Probably the easiest and neatest method, and it works great for the simple problems.

---

Second and more rigorous approach would be to use a particular definition for what $\frac{d^t}{dx^t}$ means for $t\notin\mathbb N$.  One approach can be given by

$$\frac{d^t}{dx^t}f(x)=\frac1{\Gamma(1-\{t\})}\frac{d^{\lceil t\rceil}}{dx^{\lceil t\rceil}}\int_{-\infty}^x\frac{f(x)}{(x-t)^{\{t\}}}~\mathrm dt$$

In particular, this should give

$$\frac{d^t}{dx^t}e^{ax}=a^te^{ax}$$

However, as we cannot directly exchange the integrals, it appears that $\int_0^\infty t^{s-1}e^{-t}(\ln(t))^x~\mathrm dt$ is only a regularization of $\Gamma^{(x)}(s)$ in this sense.

Comment: hmm ? you have to find a derivation of $\displaystyle\frac{d^q}{ds^q} e^{cs}$ for real $q  > 0$

Comment: @user1952009 $\frac{d^q}{ds^q}e^{cs}=c^qe^{cs}$ by induction.

Comment: how do you know it ?

Comment: @user1952009 It is rather easy actually.  $\frac d{dx}e^{cx}=ce^{cx}$, so for $n\in\mathbb N$, $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{cx}=c^ne^{cx}$, which implies this holds for $n\in\mathbb Z$, which implies using the method my answer suggests, that this holds for $n\in\mathbb{Q}\implies n\in\mathbb{R}\implies n\in\mathbb{C}$

Comment: so to be clear you don't have any proof

Comment: @user1952009 ... ? I don't understand, that derivative is well known and what not.  I'm not quite sure what you are asking for when you say you want a proof.

Comment: this is a 2 years old question whose you don't have the answer : how to define the fractional derivative such that it is a well-defined linear operator and that $D^q e^{cx} = c^q e^{cx}$

Comment: @user1952009 It is actually far beyond 2 years old and is one of the first fractional derivatives considered, like here: http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath616/kmath616.htm I am actually slightly unsure how to handle this problem using "linear operators", but I'm sure someone else can.  Sorry.

Comment: in [wiki/Fractional_calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus) there is what is needed for proving $D^q x^a = \frac{\Gamma(a+1)}{\Gamma(a+1-q)} x^{a-q}$ but it gives $D^q e^{cx} = D^q\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{c^k x^k}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty D^q  \frac{c^k x^k}{k!} =  \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{c^k x^{k-q}}{\Gamma(k+1-q)}$.... maybe using the [laplace transform definition of $D^q$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus#Laplace_transform) will be easier

Comment: @user1952009 No, actually, I do think different ways of calculating fractional derivatives may come out differently.  Which is a question I want to ask.  Plus, that's a bad way of doing it:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572828/fractional-derivative-of-a-taylor-series

Comment: the Laplace/Fourier transform definition when it converges should be compatible with the $D^q x^a = \frac{\Gamma(a+1)}{\Gamma(a+1-q)} x^{a-q}$ definition, the problem is when something does not converge

Comment: @user1952009 You know, I was actually trying to take the fractional derivative of a function via Taylor series, because that tends to make sense, but it turns out to seem slightly wrong somehow.  I don't actually know how to do those transforms, but I do note that if we have $c=1$ in your example above, you get false statements, as $D^qe^x\ne D^{q+1}e^x$, they actually come out different.

Comment: how do you know $D^{q+1} e^x \ne D^q e^x$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 I tried their Taylor series, and $D^qe^x-D^{q+1}e^x=\frac{x^{-q-1}}{\Gamma(-q)}$, which happens when you reindex the series so you can cancel off terms.  Which seems contradictory, since we should have $D^qe^x=e^x$ for any $q$.

Comment: I don't get your argument, but it seems $D^q e^x\ne e^x$ (when $q$ is not an integer) so that  the correct answer is that with the usual definition of the fractional derivative in term of the Fourier transform $D^q f = FT^{-1}[(2 i \pi \xi)^q FT[f]]$ which is the same as $D^q [x^a 1_{x > 0}] = \frac{\Gamma(a+1)}{\Gamma(a+1-q)} x^{a-q} 1_{x > 0}$ then $D^q [e^x] \ne e^x$

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, and many fractional derivative formulas point out $D^qe^x=e^x$, implying that there isn't just one way to doing these things and one answer may be just as right as the next.

Comment: don't know what those fractional derivative are meant to be, but they are probably not linear operators (on tempered distribution)

Comment: @user1952009 Sadly, I can't help you there.  Maybe not all fractional derivative formulas aren't linear operators, which I guess would be a pain for you.  :/

Comment: of course it is a problem if it is not linear ! how would you treat $D^q \sum_k c_k e^{k x}$ then ? what about the $D^q \int_0^\infty f(t,x) dt$ in the original question ? so I think the problem is to find what are the possible definition of $D^q$ such that $D^q e^{cx} = c^q e^{cx}$ and see if one of them is linear (I think they are not, but I've no proof)

Comment: @user1952009 I usually follow an induction method if the answer seems it should be obvious.  If the answer isn't, then I'd probably resort to the formula book.

Comment: so did you get why the fact it is linear is the most important ?  and try searching in your texts if you find any clear definition of $D^q$ such that $D^q e^{cx}=  c^q e^{cx}$

Comment: @user1952009 I'm sorry, but to begin with, I don't fully understand 'linear' in this context.  I haven't even studied linear algebra, so sorry.

Comment: @user1952009 Oh, well, that would strongly imply that we should be able to differentiate a function via its Taylor series... I feel as though I should study up on this.  Thanks for the inputs.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829921/do-different-methods-of-calculating-fractional-derivatives-have-to-be-equal

Comment: $D^q(a f+b g) = a D^q f + b D^q g$ (for any two functions $f,g$ and constants $a,b$) !!! this is what allows us to write (when $K$ is finite, or when $K = \infty$ and that everything converges) $D^q \sum_{k=0}^K a_k f_k = \sum_{k=0}^K a_k D^q f_k$  and yes the fact that the usual derivative is a linear operator is why we can differentiate easily so many analytic functions via their Taylor/Dirichlet/Fourier series or their integral representation (since $\int$ is a limit of $\sum$)

Comment: @user1952009 Note that if we differentiate a fractional and positive amount of times on the Taylor series, we get some $x^{-a}$ term, implying that $\lim_{x\to0}f^{(n)}(x)$ is undefined around $x=0$ for all functions?  And yet converges to something everywhere else?

Comment: I answered to that in your question on the integration constant .. $\frac{\Gamma(a+1)}{\Gamma(a-n-1)} = 0$ for $a-n-1$ a negative integer

Comment: @user1952009 Oh... I feel like this is overly complicated.  (I really don't like the constant of differ-integration...)  I'll come back to this in a few hours, thanks for the thought invoking talk.  No no, but when taking fractional derivatives, $a-n-1\notin\mathbb{Z}$, which lets the problems come in.

Comment: @reuns \**sighs*\* long time no see, how's my answer look now lol.  And while you are at it, [this new question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2361875/evaluating-psi1-2x-of-the-extended-polygamma-function) may be of interest to you.