# Evaluating $\psi^{(1/2)}(x)$ of the extended polygamma function

Tags: integration, gamma-function, fractional-calculus, polygamma

The [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) is generally given by

$$\psi^{(n)}(x)=\frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}}\ln(\Gamma(x)),~n\in\mathbb N_{\ge0}$$

where $\Gamma$ is the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).  This can be extended to negative integers by letting

$$\psi^{(n-1)}(x)=\int_a^x\psi^{(n)}(x)$$

Unfortunately, there is no fixed $a$ such that the above holds true for any $n$, but it does capture the general idea.

Using [fractional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus), one can extend the polygamma function to complex values.  Here, I could have

$$\psi^{(z)}_u(x)=\frac1{\Gamma(1-\{a\}-bi)}\frac{d^{\lceil a\rceil+2}}{dx^{\lceil a\rceil+2}}\int_u^x\frac{\ln(\Gamma(t))}{(x-t)^{\{a\}+bi}}~\mathrm dt$$

where $z=a+bi$, $a>-1$, $\lceil a\rceil$ is the ceiling function, and $\{a\}$ is the fractional part of $a$.  $u$ could be any constant such that the integral converges.  For $z\in\mathbb R^+$, the above expression reduces down to the normal polygamma function regardless of $u$ (at least for $x>0$).

For $a<-1$,

$$\psi^{(z)}_u(x)=\frac1{\Gamma(z)}\int_u^x(x-t)^{z-1}\ln(\Gamma(t))~\mathrm dt$$

---

Particularly of interest, I'm trying to find the closed form of $\psi^{(1/2)}_u(x)$.

$$\psi^{(1/2)}_u(x)=\frac1{\sqrt\pi}\frac{d^3}{dx^3}\int_u^x\frac{\ln(\Gamma(t))}{\sqrt{x-t}}~\mathrm dt$$

By applying [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), this reduces down to

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_u^x\frac{\ln(\Gamma(t))}{\sqrt{x-t}}~\mathrm dt=\lim_{y\to x}\left[\frac{\ln(\Gamma(y))}{\sqrt{x-y}}-\frac12\int_u^y\frac{\ln(\Gamma(t))}{(x-t)^{3/2}}~\mathrm dt\right]$$

However, I can't figure out how to simplify this, if possible. Trying to attack the original integral, then differentiating the result, I'm tempted to use [this series expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2310697/how-can-we-show-that-sum-n-1-infty-leftx-over-n-lnnx-over-n-right/2310703#2310703), but integrating term by term of that expression is quite nasty and the resulting series looks quite doubtful from anywhere near a closed form.

Also unsure if this is any help, but if we appropriately define $\sqrt z=|z|^{1/2}e^{i\theta/2}$, where $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$, one could attempt a keyhole contour of radius $u$ centered at $x$ to deduce that (hopefully this is correct)

$$\int_u^x\frac{\ln(\Gamma(t))}{\sqrt{x-t}}~\mathrm dt=\frac12\int_\pi^{3\pi}\frac{\Gamma(x+ue^{i\theta})}{\sqrt{-ue^{i\theta}}}~d\theta$$

But again, doesn't seem much helpful

Comment: I'm not sure, but if memory serves me right, there was recently a question along the lines of the integral of $x^2\ln(\Gamma(x))$?

Answer (score 1):

What about applying a fractional derivative to each term of the Kummer-Malmsten Fourier series for $\log\Gamma$? It is not difficult to apply $D^{\alpha}$ (fractional derivative with respect to $x$) to the integral representation

$$ \psi(x)=\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{e^{-t}}{t}-\frac{e^{-xt}}{1-e^{-t}}\right)\, dt,$$
too.

Comment: I still don't think this gets us any closer to any closed form.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: I do not think a nice closed form exists, but the approach above should lead to a representation in terms of a series depending on the (imaginary) error function.

Answer (score 1):

#### Introduction

As is usually the case with [Fractional Derivatives](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalDerivative.html), there is also not "the [Fractional Derivatives](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalDerivative.html)" for the [Polygamma Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html) $\psi^{\left( \alpha \right)}\left( \cdot \right) = \psi_{\alpha}\left( \cdot \right) = \psi\left( \alpha,\, \cdot \right)$ (i'll use the notation $\psi^{\left( \alpha \right)}\left( \cdot \right)$). They differ depending on the method of derivation used and the type of Differential operator.

#### Manual Calculation of the Fractional Derivative

##### Calculation Via Series Expansion

The [Polygamma Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html) $\psi^{\left( \alpha \right)}\left( z \right)$ has a usefull series expansion for $\alpha > 0$ ($\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$) given by
$$
\begin{align*}
\psi^{\left( \alpha \right)}\left( z \right) &= \left( -1 \right)^{\alpha + 1} \cdot \alpha! \cdot \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left[ \left( z + k \right)^{-\alpha - 1} \right]\\
&\text{or}\\
\psi^{\left( \alpha \right)}\left( z \right) &= \left( -1 \right)^{\alpha + 1} \cdot \Gamma\left( \alpha + 1 \right) \cdot \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left[ \left( z + k \right)^{-\alpha - 1} \right]\
\end{align*}
$$
where $\Gamma\left( \cdot \right)$ ist the [Complte Gamma Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FaadiBrunosFormula.html).

If we insert $\alpha = 0.5$ we get:
$$
\begin{align*}
\psi^{\left( 0.5 \right)}\left( z \right) &= \left( -1 \right)^{0.5 + 1} \cdot \Gamma\left( 0.5 + 1 \right) \cdot \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left[ \left( z + k \right)^{-0.5 - 1} \right]\\
\psi^{\left( 0.5 \right)}\left( z \right) &= \left( -1 \right)^{1.5} \cdot \Gamma\left( 1.5 \right) \cdot \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left[ \left( z + k \right)^{-1.5} \right]\\
\end{align*}
$$

The whole thing can be simplified with the [Hurwitz Zeta Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HurwitzZetaFunction.html) $\zeta\left( \alpha,\, z \right)$:
$$\fbox{$
\begin{align*}
\psi^{\left( 0.5 \right)}\left( z \right) &= \left( -1 \right)^{1.5} \cdot \Gamma\left( 1.5 \right) \cdot \zeta\left( 1.5,\, z \right)\\
\psi^{\left( 0.5 \right)}\left( z \right) &= \pm i \cdot \Gamma\left( 1.5 \right) \cdot \zeta\left( 1.5,\, z \right)\\
\end{align*}
$} \tag{1}$$

But $\left( -1 \right)^{1.5} = \left( -1 \right)^{\frac{3}{2}}$ has a different solution depending on the branch. The main branch gives $\left( -1 \right)^{1.5} = i$ and the other branch $\left( -1 \right)^{1.5} = -i$ where $i^{2} = -1$. This would give you utible possible [Polygamma Functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html).

Plot for $\left( -1 \right)^{1.5} = i$:

[image: "Plot[i Gamma[1.5] HurwitzZeta[1.5, x], {x, -10, 10}]" by Wolfram|Alpha]

Plot for $\left( -1 \right)^{1.5} = -i$:

[image: "Plot[-(i Gamma[1.5] HurwitzZeta[1.5, x]), {x, -10, 10}]" by Wolfram|Alpha]

##### "Euler Method"

Euler had come up with his own method for some [Fractional Derivatives](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalDerivative.html) (see Euler's Approach). He has sorted the derivatives of the function by order and is trying to find a pattern in it. He then tried to transfer this pattern from integer orders to fractional ones.

But here is a problem. Without knowledge of special functions, one cannot come up with a general formula for a Derivative of the $\alpha$th order. We would only come up with a special case of [Faà di Bruno's Formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FaadiBrunosFormula.html).

However, if we write the derivatives in terms of certain special functions, such as the [Hurwitz Zeta Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HurwitzZetaFunction.html) $\zeta\left( \alpha,\, \cdot \right)$ or the [Bernoulli Polynomials](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliPolynomial.html) $B_{\alpha}\left( \cdot \right)$ or the [Polylogarithm](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html), we might find such a generalization.

Since I have already carried out a possible derivation of such a [Fractional Derivative](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalDerivative.html) with the [Hurwitz Zeta Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HurwitzZetaFunction.html), I will demonstrate it here with the [Bernoulli Polynomials](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliPolynomial.html). I'll use $\operatorname{D_{x}^{\alpha}}$ given as a differential operator by $\operatorname{D_{x}^{\alpha}} = \frac{\operatorname{d}^{\alpha}}{\operatorname{d}x^{\alpha}}$ for $a \geq 0$, wich is also true for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{D_{x}^{0}}\left[ \psi^{0}\left( z \right) \right] = \psi^{0}\left( z \right) &= +\psi^{0}\left( z \right)\\
\operatorname{D_{x}^{1}}\left[ \psi^{0}\left( z \right) \right] = \psi^{1}\left( z \right) &= -B_{-1}\left( z \right)\\
\operatorname{D_{x}^{2}}\left[ \psi^{0}\left( z \right) \right] = \psi^{2}\left( z \right) &= +B_{-2}\left( z \right)\\
\operatorname{D_{x}^{3}}\left[ \psi^{0}\left( z \right) \right] = \psi^{3}\left( z \right) &= -2 \cdot B_{-3}\left( z \right)\\
\operatorname{D_{x}^{4}}\left[ \psi^{0}\left( z \right) \right] = \psi^{4}\left( z \right) &= +6 \cdot B_{-4}\left( z \right)\\
\operatorname{D_{x}^{5}}\left[ \psi^{0}\left( z \right) \right] = \psi^{5}\left( z \right) &= -24 \cdot B_{-5}\left( z \right)\\
&\cdots\\
\operatorname{D_{x}^{n}}\left[ \psi^{0}\left( z \right) \right] = \psi^{n}\left( z \right) &= \left( -1 \right)^{n} \cdot \left( n - 1 \right)! \cdot B_{-n}\left( z \right),\, \text{for}\, n \in \mathbb{N}\\
\operatorname{D_{x}^{\alpha}}\left[ \psi^{0}\left( z \right) \right] = \psi^{\alpha}\left( z \right) &= \left( -1 \right)^{\alpha} \cdot \Gamma\left( \alpha \right) \cdot B_{-\alpha}\left( z \right),\, \text{for}\, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{+}\\
\end{align*}
$$
where $\Gamma\left( \cdot \right)$ ist the [Complte Gamma Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FaadiBrunosFormula.html).

Substituting $\alpha = 0.5$ into the generalized formula we get:
$$
\begin{align*}
\psi^{0.5}\left( z \right) &= \left( -1 \right)^{\alpha} \cdot \Gamma\left( \alpha \right) \cdot B_{-\alpha}\left( z \right)\\
\psi^{0.5}\left( z \right) &= \left( -1 \right)^{0.5} \cdot \Gamma\left( 0.5 \right) \cdot B_{-0.5}\left( z \right)\\
\psi^{0.5}\left( z \right) &= \sqrt{-1} \cdot \Gamma\left( 0.5 \right) \cdot B_{-0.5}\left( z \right)\\
\psi^{\alpha}\left( z \right) &= \pm i \cdot \Gamma\left( 0.5 \right) \cdot B_{-0.5}\left( z \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$
where $i^{2} = -1$
Here, too, as we can see, we get several possible branches and thus several possible functions:

$$\fbox{$
\begin{align*}
\psi^{\left( 0.5 \right)}\left( z \right) &= \sqrt{-1} \cdot \Gamma\left( 0.5 \right) \cdot B_{-0.5}\left( z \right)\\
\psi^{\left( 0.5 \right)}\left( z \right) &= \pm i \cdot \Gamma\left( 0.5 \right) \cdot B_{-0.5}\left( z \right)\\
\end{align*}
$} \tag{2}$$

Plot for $\left( -1 \right)^{1.5} = i$:

[image: "Plot[i Gamma[1.5] NorlundB[-0.5,1,x], {x, -10, 10}]" by Wolfram|Alpha]

Plot for $\left( -1 \right)^{1.5} = -i$:

[image: "Plot[-(i Gamma[1.5] NorlundB[-0.5,1,x]), {x, -10, 10}]" by Wolfram|Alpha]

Yes. And you guessed it. They are the same as before.

##### Calculation Via Using Special Differential Operators

###### Riemann–Liouville Operator

The [Riemann–Liouville Fractional Operator](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html), on the other hand, uses the formulas for simplifying mutible integrals into single integral for many other differential operators:
$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{_{a}D^{-v}_{x}}\left[ f\left( x \right) \right] \equiv \frac{1}{\Gamma\left( v \right)} \cdot \int\limits_{a}^{x} f\left( u \right) \cdot \left( x - u \right)^{v - 1} \, \operatorname{d}u \tag{3}\\
\end{align*}
$$
where $\Gamma\left( \cdot \right)$ ist the [Complte Gamma Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FaadiBrunosFormula.html).

This operator has a so-called Convolutional Formula, wich is just  spezial case with $a = 0$, but it also takes advantage of the fact that integrating and deriving cancel each other out:
$$
\begin{align*}\operatorname{_{0}D^{v}_{x}}\left[ f\left( x \right) \right] \equiv \frac{1}{\Gamma\left( 1 - v \right)} \cdot \operatorname{D^{1}_{x}}\left[ \int\limits_{0}^{x} f\left( u \right) \cdot \left( x - u \right)^{-v}\, \operatorname{d}u \right] \tag{4}\\
\end{align*}
$$

So we get:
$$
\begin{align*}
\psi^{\left( 0.5 \right)}\left( x \right) = \operatorname{_{0}D^{0.5}_{x}}\left[ \psi^{\left( 0 \right)}\left( x \right) \right] &\equiv \frac{1}{\Gamma\left( 0.5 \right)} \cdot \operatorname{D^{1}_{x}}\left[ \int\limits_{0}^{x} \psi^{\left( 0 \right)}\left( u \right) \cdot \left( x - u \right)^{-0.5}\, \operatorname{d}u \right] \tag{5}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Using Formula $\left( 5 \right)$ gives you a simplification of your Problem. But I'll leave the solution with this formula to you as an exercise for you.

#### Mathematical Softwares

Up to now, only a few programs can determine derivatives of fractional order, and those that can can only do so for a few specific functions.

The best-known example of this is probably [Wolfram|Alpha](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalDerivative.html): The command `FractionalD[f[x], {x, α}]` gives the [Riemann–Liouville Fractional Derivative](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html) of order $\alpha$ of the function $f$ with respect of $x$ ($\operatorname{_{0}D^{\alpha}_{x}}\left( f\left( x \right) \right)$). However, this only works for a few functions so far like some monomials. [Wolfram|Alpha](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalDerivative.html) also has a small article about the command in which they explain the possibilities that the command opens up (see [Wolfram > Language > Reference > FractionalD](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HurwitzZetaFunction.html)). There is also the command `CaputoD[f, {x, α}]`, wich gives the Caputo Fractional Differintegral of order $\alpha$ of the function $f$ with respect of $x$ ($\operatorname{_{0}^{C}D^{\alpha}_{x}}\left( f\left( x \right) \right)$). [Wolfram|Alpha](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalDerivative.html) has also a small article about the command in which they explain the possibilities that the command opens up (see [Wolfram > Language > Reference > CaputoD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKjGd.png)).

Although [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) cannot fractionally differentiate the [Polygamma Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html) $\psi^{\left( \alpha \right)}\left( z \right)$ (`Polygamma[a, z]`), it can calculate and plot the [Polygamma Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html) $\psi^{\left( 0.5 \right)}\left( z \right)$.

It uses the following series expansions:

around $x = 0$:
$$
\begin{align*}
&\psi^{\left( 0.5 \right)}\left( x \right) \approx x^{-0.5} \cdot \left( \frac{0.282095 \cdot \ln\left( x \right) - 0.173123}{x} - 0.325659 + 1.85611 \cdot x - 1.8085 \cdot x^{2} + 1.95403 \cdot x^{3} - 2.13952 \cdot x^{4} + 2.33234 \cdot x^{5} + \mathcal{O}\left( x^{6} \right) \right) \tag{6}\\
\end{align*}
$$

around $x = \infty$:
$$
\begin{align*}
&\psi^{\left( 0.5 \right)}\left( x \right) \approx x^{-0.5} \cdot \left( 0.56419 \cdot \ln\left( x \right) + 0.782133 + \frac{0.141047 \cdot \ln\left( x \right) - 0.345789}{x} + \frac{0.0352618 \cdot \ln\left( x \right) + 0.0601102}{x^2} - \frac{0.016105}{x^{3}} + \frac{-0.00514235 \cdot \ln\left( x \right) - 0.00263636}{x^{4}} + \frac{0.0055425}{x^{5}} + \mathcal{O}\left( \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)^{6} \right) \right) \tag{7}\\
\end{align*}
$$

A plot of this definition would look like this:

[image: Plot of Polygamma[0.5, x] by Wolfram|Alpha]